# MySQL Workbench 5.2.42 crash on startup on Win7 x64

Tags: .net, windows, visual-c++, mysql-workbench

I have a win7 x64 system (i3, nvidia card) and I want to use MySQL Workbench, but after launching it crashes with the following message:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: MySQLWorkbench.exe
  Application Version:  5.2.42.9752
  Application Timestamp:    50243f32
  Fault Module Name:    wbprivate.be.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   50243a9e
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0025e562
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1049
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I was searching about this issue, and found few possible solutions, like deleting Workbench folder in AppData or reinstalling .NET or reinstalling Visual C x86 from Microsoft, but nothing was helpful. Thanks for help.

Comment: Don't upgrade, 5.2.42 is extremely buggy, it looks more like a *very* early beta. Crashes on every other query, loses default databases, context menus displayed for wrong context, horrible experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you download WB as a installerless zipfile? The problem might be with the executable files (exe, dll etc) being blocked by Windows with this warning "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer".

If you unblock your zipfile before unpacking the contents no files will be blocked and hopefully WB will run without problems. See for example [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/38476/this-file-came-from-another-computer-how-can-i-unblock-all-the-files-in-a).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried what you suggested, but I solved it just by switching from external nvidia video card to built-in intel gma card. I saw many posts, where the issue was because of ati video card, but not nvidia. So recomendation to all, who will have such issue is to keep up to date video drivers or try to switch to another video card.